# how do I connect to postgresql installed in my Ubuntu within Windows Subsystem?

Tags: networking, postgresql

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 within the "Windows Subsystem for Linux"

Within Ubuntu itself, I installed Postgresql 11 and I can connect to it using psql.

Now, what is the address of my postgres server from Windows?

I would like to access it using DBeaver.

Comment: From within ubuntu, I find something that looks like my ubuntu ip address using `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` and I know my postgres port is 5432 but it times out when trying to connect through dbeaver

Comment: I can ping that IP address from windows